# C++ how to get type of enum

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I have such enum:

```
enum HTTPRequestMethods {GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, CONNECT, OPTIONS, TRACE, PATCH};
```

I would like to write interface for my code that then I'll be able to use any other internet library in my code just writing a new interface implementation. Because I need some speed (that's why I write my project in C++, because in Python I tried it is slow even if use fastest libraries) I thought write the interface using CRTP.

Also I would like to use templates for URL for less branching in runtime, just writing specific function for every HTTPRequestMethod:

```
template <decltype(HTTPRequestMethods::GET) Method>
struct URL {
    explicit URL(std::string web_url, std::string path) : web_url(web_url), path(path) {}
    std::string web_url;
    std::string path;
};

template <typename InterfaceImplementation>
struct InternetInterface {

    template <decltype(HTTPRequestMethods::GET) HTTPRequestMethod>
    std::string_view getBody(URL<HTTPRequestMethod> url) {
        return static_cast<InterfaceImplementation>(this).getBody<HTTPRequestMethod>(url);
    }
};

struct APIWrapper : InternetInterface<APIWrapper> {
    
    ...

    template <decltype(HTTPRequestMethods::GET) HTTPRequestMethod>
    std::string_view getBody(URL<HTTPRequestMethod> url_);


private:
    ...
};

// template specializations:
// for GET
template <>
std::string_view APIWrapper::getBody(URL<HTTPRequestMethods::GET> url) {
    ...
}
...
```

Is there another way to get type of enum than `decltype(enum_name::any_value)` ?

Comment: consider using `enum class`. That will simplify many things, including getting its type, as well as avoid many plain `enum` pitfalls.

Comment: I would consider making any of those request methods a class (struct). You could still keep your current templatized code (no runtime polymorphism if you don't want). Each concrete class could as well implement some interface (e.g. deriving all from an `HttpRequestMethod`).

Comment: The name of the enum *is* the type.  No need for decltype. All of `GET`, `PUT`, and `POST` are of the type `HTTPRequestMethods `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer your question - using `decltype` is a correct way to obtain a type of an enum.

### TLDR

Keep in mind, that `decltype` yields you a **type**, in your case, the type of `HTTPRequestMethods::GET` and `HTTPRequestMethods::POST` is exactly the same - it will be `HTTPRequestMethods`.

You can verify it with `static_assert` and `std::is_same_v` like this:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(HTTPRequestMethods::GET), HTTPRequestMethods>,
                  "This should be the same");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(HTTPRequestMethods::PATCH), HTTPRequestMethods>,
                  "This should be the same");
```

What you need is a [non-type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter) as opposed to a [type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Type_template_parameter). Here is a small example:

```
template <HTTPRequestMethods Method>
struct URL {
    std::string web_url;
    std::string path;
};

template <>
struct URL<HTTPRequestMethods::PUT> {
    std::string put_only;
};
```

This way, the `URL<HTTPRequestMethods::GET>` and the `URL<HTTPRequestMethods::PUT>` are different types. Since these are different types, you can provide standard overloads:

```
void print_url(const URL<HTTPRequestMethods::GET>& url) {
    std::cout << "web_url = " << url.web_url << "\n";
    // (...)
}

void print_url(const URL<HTTPRequestMethods::PUT>& url) {
    std::cout << "put_only = " << url.put_only << "\n";
    // (...)
}
```